# UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES due to Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect in Play 2.2.2?

Tags: playframework, sbt

I am new to Play Framework and have not been able to add a managed dependency.

Version of Play is **2.2.2** and sbt is **0.13.0**.

In the example below I try to "manage"/download(?) the Apache Derby library but I've also tried with several others and lots of different resolvers. The library ends up as a unresolved dependency.

I've read about managing dependencies in http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.2/SBTDependencies.

I've tried with a bunch of different libraries and made sure that they are accessible and that the resolvers are correct. The problem is not with firewall/proxy, since I tested by connecting directly to the internet.

Setup for the **build.sbt** is like the following (I've tried every imaginable variation):

```
name := "kursguiden"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

resolvers += "Maven Central" at "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/"

resolvers += "mvnrepository" at "http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.derby" % "derby" % "10.4.1.3",
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache
)     

play.Project.playJavaSettings
```

and the **plugins.sbt**:

```
// Comment to get more information during initialization
logLevel := Level.Warn

// The Typesafe repository
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.2")
```

When I run `play update` or `play run` I get this error message in the play console:

```
[kursguiden] $ update
[info] Updating {file:/C:/play/kursguiden/}kursguiden...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.3 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache.derby#derby;10.4.1.3 ...
[error] Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo1.mave
n.org/maven2/org/apache/derby/derby/10.4.1.3/derby-10.4.1.3.pom
[error] Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo1.mave
n.org/maven2/org/apache/derby/derby/10.4.1.3/derby-10.4.1.3.pom
[error] Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://mvnreposit
ory.com/artifact/org/apache/derby/derby/10.4.1.3/derby-10.4.1.3.pom

.
.
.

[info] Resolving commons-io#commons-io;2.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.10.3 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#jline;2.10.3 ...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
warn]  :: org.apache.derby#derby;10.4.1.3: not found
warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.derby
derby;10.4.1.3: not found
error] Total time: 422 s, completed 2014-mar-20 23:11:27
```

This is just one example thats been tried. spent the last 8 hours on this problem :)

What do you think could be the problem? I can access all the files via browser so my clue is that there must be some strange setting somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your build files worked for me. It appears that `Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect` was a temporary network issue with your connection or the server itself. Give it a try again.

You may also want to remove the following `resolvers` from **build.sbt** as I believe they're not needed (at least the last one):

```
resolvers += "Maven Central" at "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/"

resolvers += "mvnrepository" at "http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/"
```

Comment: Thanks for verifying! You were completely right, apparently I had a process of "Zone alarm" still running in the background that didnt show up in the system tray. I definitely wont forget to check for that in the future..